# Ruby on rails route to root not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, root

I'm using Jquery 1.9.1 and Jquery Mobile 1.3.2 to make the face of a mobile app. I'm using Ruby on Rails 4 to develop the app and database structures.

I cannot use my Routes file correctly to get my / path to route to the /home path. Here's the code:

```
Sapp::Application.routes.draw do
    root "pages#home"
    get '/about', to: 'pages#about'
end
```

When I go to / I get code, and I can't tell where this code is coming from but its not pages/home code, check out this data it gives me in the browser (minus Quotes):

"<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %> <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %> <%= csrf_meta_tags %> <%= yield %>"

So maybe its my Jquery or something that is messing up the normal welcome page or seomthing but I can't figure out why the code doesn't work:

```
root "pages#home"
```

Can you help me?

Comment: PS. the Get about code does work correctly. and I can do the same to get /home to work but not the root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the problem was but I created a new project using devise and this time I installed the jquery Gem - I'm not sure if I installed the gem the first time or just included the javascript files, I don't remember. but I basically started over and this time it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the ERB tags in your root layout are not being evaluated to HTML.

In order for ERB tags to be evaluated to HTML, you need to use [ERB templating](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html). Do this by renaming your root layout template – likely `application.html` – to `application.html.erb`. Similarly, ensure that all templates which require ERB evaluation are suffixed by the `.erb` file extension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think that's it. I have no .html files in my assets folder. the application file is application.html.erb and the code in it is
'<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title><%= title %></title><%= csrf_meta_tags %><%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %></head><body><%= yield %></body></html>'